# How to delete an element from an array of element

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I've created a method in my utils.ts to delete an element from an array.

```
public static deleteElementFromArray<T>(list: T[], element: T): T[] {
    if (!list) {
      return [];
    }
    const index = list.indexOf(element);
    if (index > -1) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return list;
}
```

a friend of mine tell me that he uses `filter` to filter the list and exclude the element.

```
users = users.filter(u => u !== toto);
```

I wonder what you think of this and if you have a better solution

Comment: `filter` is perfectly fine to use. Do you have any specific concerns with it? It's more readable certainly

Comment: They both do the same thing in this instance, `splice` is probably more efficient though by working on the array directly. `filter` rebuilds a new array based on the predicate you supply.

Comment: If you process a few thousand arrays with a few thpusand elements, use the first as it is faster. Otherwise use the last one as it is pure and more readable.

Comment: I'm not up to speed with JavaScript so this is an honest question: Is this mixing Java and JavaScript? Does `public static` actually exist in JS along with generic types (`<T>`)?

Comment: @Matt Actually this used to be tagged Typescript, but since it's really a JavaScript question, I replaced TypeScript with JavaScript. Arguably I should add the typescript tag back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- splice - Remove an element from array
- filter - Not modifying original
  array and will create new filtered array

See this link: https://medium.com/@justintulk/javascript-performance-array-slice-vs-array-filter-4573d726aacb

Test: https://jsperf.com/array-splice-vs-array-filter/1

Answer (score 0):

Either solution is fine, a more detailed answer can be found here:
[How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Just take in consideration that the notation for anonymous function '=>' may not be implemented in al browsers.